# Matlab: template matching using vectorization

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to improve speed of this code, but I can't understand how to use vectorization here (instead of for-loop). The function is from my impementation of [SAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences#Example) using [template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching#Template-based_matching_and_convolution).

```
function [diffs,time] = search(template,image)
[hT,wT] = size(template);
[hI,wI] = size(image);
h = hI-hT+1;
w = wI-wT+1;
diffs = zeros(h,w);
tic;
for i = 1:h
    for j = 1:w
        t = image(i:i+hT-1,j:j+wT-1)-template(:,:);     % ???
        diffs(i,j) = sum(sum(abs(t)));
    end
end
time = toc;
```

For an image of 640x480 this function works about 22-25 seconds.

Comment: What is the size of template?

Comment: Depends on image. In my case it was 480x360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use the `im2col` function on the image and `repmat` with your initial template.

```
im_v = im2col(image,[hT wT]);
template_v = repmat(template(:),1,size(im_v,2));
```

`im_v` will store column vectors of every `hT x wT` block of your matrix.  Now, you can perform any function you'd like between `im_v` and `template_v`.

Comment: I tried that, but it failed du to a "out of memory", even when the template was only 20x20... also you can avoid using `repmat`, by using `bsxfun`

Comment: Good to know.  I've been working with very small images so I hadn't tried scaling my solution up.

Answer (score 1):

If your template has size 480*360 and your image 640*480, in total you want to do 480*360*480*640=5.3084e+10 opérations.

So, I don't think you can go much faster than 22-25 seconds.

In your case, the code inside the loop is quite big and vectorized, so you would not gain much by factorizing.

If your template was much smaller, you could use the function `im2col` to vectorize, but since your template is very big, it would take too much RAM memory.